# a crossover repeated measure feed trial using R

Tags: r, repeated-measures, outliers, crossover-study

I attempt to analyse a crossover feed trial using R but I`m not good at statistical analysis.
My data contains 10 subjects, equally divided into 2 groups named A and B. Each group were fed with diet A or B respectively according to different period. Each period contain 14 days. Day 0 represent the last day of period 1.
[image: Feed Trial]

part of my data are as follows, **stage** represent different days and **treatment** represent different diet

[image: part of data]

I googled some information about repeated measurement. I guess a mixed linear model may work for me, with subject as a random effect and stage, group, treatment as fixed effect. Using **lme4** package.

```
model = lme(VFA ~ Stage + Group + Treatment + (1|Subject), data=acetate)
```

Because my trial is a mix with crossover and repeated measurement, I`m not sure whether the model is right or not. And also I want to dig out more useful information from my data.

another question is about how to find out the outliers in the data.
Thank you for your help